# Concavity of trig function

Tags: education

The original function is:`x^2-4x+7cos(x)`
I attempted to find concavity on the interval `[-4,4]`using mathematica but i'm not quite there yet[image]

Comment: The points in red are not actually inflection points! The concavity of `h` only changes at the `x`-values marked in black. Test: curve your hand like a C and hold your arm in front of you so that your forearm is parallel to the x-axis. Can you adjust your hand so that it fits the curve `h`? If so, it's concave-down. (Which hand you use doesn't matter.)

Comment: oh I see thank you! I just assumed that when the graph changes the shape of its curve like shown it indicates a change in concavity

Comment: so the inflection points are -arccos(2/7) and arccos(2/7)?

Comment: yup! that's right. (Note the change in sign that we see here is important.)

Answer (score 2):

An automatic approach is as follows.

```
FunctionConvexity[{x^2 - 4 x + 7*Cos[x], RealAbs[x] <= 4}, x]
```

> `Indeterminate`

This means that the funciton under consideration is neither convex nor concave on the interval `x >= -4, x <= 4`. See the documentation for more info.

Comment: Moreover, `FunctionConvexity[{x^2 - a*x + 7*Cos[x], RealAbs[x] <= 4}, x, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` results in `ConditionalExpression[
 Indeterminate, Element[a, 
  Reals]]`. This means the function is neither convex nor concave on `x>=-4,x<=4`  for each real value of `a`